# Does Ubuntu block the single user mode without password

Tags: password, root, single-user

Today I try to use the way that I've known for several years to enter the Single User mode: enter the edit mode of grub and add `single` at the end of line of `kernel` and type `F10`.

I thought I could enter the Single User mode without typing password but to my surprise, it asked me to type the root password. I don't know why because I always used this way to rescue my linux system, for example, if I lost the root password, I could use this way to make a new root password.

But now things changed...

So Ubuntu has blocked this non-password single user mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So Ubuntu has blocked this non-password single user mode?

No. The single user mode does ask a password if there is one set for "root" but that is not the default.

> to type the root password

Ubuntu does not work with "root" and the password for "root" is set/disabled on installation.

And then there is systemd. See if ...

```
grep ExecStart /usr/lib/systemd/system/rescue.service
```

returns a "sulogin"  then that is a reason for asking for a password. The parameters in that line will explain what is asked.

---

The [man page for sulogin](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/sulogin.8.html) explains its behaviour:

```
sulogin is invoked by init when the system goes into single-user mode.

The user is prompted:

      Give root password for system maintenance
      (or type Control-D for normal startup):

If the root account is locked and --force is specified, no password is required.
```

Comment: So, I can't login single user mode if someone has set the password for root; and If I add `--force` in `rescue.service`, I can login signer user mode even if the password of root has been set?

Comment: @Yves no. "If the root account is locked AND --force is specified". Both apply, not a single one of these 2.

Comment: @steeldriver guessing ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want single user mode to prompt for a password, the file responsible is `/lib/systemd/system/rescue.service`, specifically the `ExecStart` line, however, it's inadvisable to edit this file directly as it may get overwritten.

Instead, we need to create an override file for it like this:

```
systemctl edit rescue.service
```

This will open a text editor.  Add these lines:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=-/bin/bash
```

(FYI: the blank `ExecStart=` is mandatory to unset the existing value before setting it to what we want)

Now save the file, and it will create a file `/etc/systemd/system/rescue.service.d/override.conf` the contents of which will override `/lib/systemd/system/rescue.service`

You will also need to make sure the package `friendly-recovery` is uninstalled as it will prevent this from working

`apt purge friendly-receovery`

Uninstalling the package should automatically invoke `update-grub` but if it doesn't you may need to run it manually.

If you want to revert to the default behavior (prompt for root password), delete the `/etc/systemd/system/rescue.service.d/override.conf` file you created and (if desired) reinstall the `friendly-recovery` package.